# Magneto 2: How to get page title from URL key

Tags: magento2

I need to get page title by URL key.

I have Breadcrumbs URLs with also product URL.

Need to show title as per URLS in breadcrumbs.

```
Eg:
http://localhost/magento2.4/
http://localhost/magento2.4/Default/
http://localhost/magento2.4/Default/argus-all-weather-tank.html
```

There are three urls. On the basis of URL key, wants to get page title.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have product object?

Comment: Updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

I needed this very thing myself as our marketing people wanted to know what "page title" a customer signed up from (we post a form into our CRM system when a customer account is created).  So, I wanted to be able to go from the session's URL before the customer account create form and determine the "page title".

This is a bit crazy, but here is what you need to do (I embodied this into a Helper):

```
<?php  
namespace Whizzbang\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;


/**
 * Class UrlTitle
 * @package Whizzbang\Helper
 */
class UrlTitle extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface
     */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $pageRepository;

    /**
     * Config constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Page $page
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        Logger  $logger,
        Context $context,
        \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Find a url from a request url on the current store
     *
     * @param string $requestPath
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getTitleFromPath(string $requestPath, int $storeId) : ?string
    {
        $title = null;
        // make path relative
        if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+(\/.*)$/', $requestPath, $matches)) {
            $requestPath = $matches[1];
        }
        if ((substr($requestPath, 0, 1) === '/') && ($requestPath !== '/')) {
            $requestPath = ltrim($requestPath, '/');
        }
        $findParam = ['request_path' => $requestPath, 'store_id' => $storeId];
        $rwInfo = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($findParam);
        if ($rwInfo) {
            while ($rwInfo && $rwInfo->getRedirectType() > 0) {
                $findParam['request_path'] = $rwInfo->getTargetPath();
                $rwInfo = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($findParam);
            }
        } else {
            // Try looking the path up as a target path
            unset($findParam['request_path']);
            $findParam['target_path'] = $requestPath;
            $rwInfo = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($findParam);
            if ($rwInfo && ($rwInfo->getEntityType() === 'custom')) {
                // Ignore custom redirect TO this destination
                $rwInfo = null;
            }
        }
        if ($rwInfo) {
            $rwType = $rwInfo->getEntityType();
            $rwEid = $rwInfo->getEntityId();
            switch ($rwType) {
                case 'product':
                    $entity = $this->productRepository->getById($rwEid);
                    if ($entity) { $title = "Product[${rwEid}]: ".$entity->getName(); }
                    break;
                case 'category':
                    $entity = $this->categoryRepository->get($rwEid, $storeId);
                    if ($entity) { $title = "Category[${rwEid}]: ".$entity->getName(); }
                    break;
                case 'cms-page':
                    $entity = $this->pageRepository->getById($rwEid);
                    if ($entity) { $title = "Page[${rwEid}]: ".$entity->getTitle(); }
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->logger->error("URL resolve '${requestPath}' -> unexpected ${rwType}[${rwEid}]");
                    return null;
            }
            if (empty($title)) { $this->logger->error("${rwType}[${rwEid}] -> ENTITY NOT FOUND!"); }
        }
        if ($title) {
            $this->logger->debug("URL '${requestPath}' -> ${rwType}[${rwEid}] -> ${title}");
        } else {
            $this->logger->warn("Unable to locate title for '${requestPath}'");
        }
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Note: If you have any 3rd party modules that have URL routes that point to other objects (eg: like Magefan Blog), then you would need to modify this code to take those routes into account.

Comment: hi Hans, would you be so kind to remove the 3rd party extension code from your answer? those lines are not relevant to the question, you should limit it to Magento code only.

Comment: Updated to remove Magefan Blog example code.